# What's the recommended way in Visual Studio with TACO to maintain both a web hosted SPA and a hybrid app?

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015, single-page-application

I do not want to build a "Hosted App." 
I do want to have a Single Page App hosted on the web. I want that same UI also as a Cordova hybrid app.
Does this require maintaining two separate projects in the solution with shared HTML and CSS files or is there a best practice I am missing here?

Comment: Do you mean you want a Single Page Web App? And by "I want that same UI also as a Cordova hybrid app.", I don't get it, cordova leverage the web UI. So what do you mean by "same UI as Cordova hybrid app"?

Comment: Yes, I want a Single Page Web App, available over the web, and that same html5+css3+js also available as a Hybrid app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want that same UI also as a Cordova hybrid app. Does this require maintaining two separate projects in the solution with shared HTML and CSS files or is there a best practice I am missing here?

Yes, you need to maintain two separate projects in the solution with shared HTML,CSS and JS files. There is no project type that you can run both as cordova app and as web app.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info. Actually helps quite a lot, as I was not sure if I was missing something and doing superfluous work.